# do not understand Class<? extends VersionedProtocol> protocol;

Tags: java

When reading a java program, I meet the following piece line of code

```
Class<? extends VersionedProtocol> protocol;
```

What does the `<? extends VersionedProtocol>` stand for? Is this a mechanism to define a class?

Comment: Read this - [Bounded Wildcards](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. No. That link is not displaying correctly due to space in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Class` class has a generic type parameter that represents itself.  So here `Class<? extends VersionedProtocol>` means a `Class` object representing the `VersionedProtocol` class or a subclass of `VersionedProtocol`.

This is known as an [upper-bounded wildcard in Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go into details for Java generic concept, Just keep in mind the below points and you could still read the program without any problem.

1. The generics are mainly for compile time safety, so these are absent at runtime.
2. You could read `Class<? extends VersionedProtocol> protocol;`  same as `Class protocol;`

So, whereever you are encountering the generic syntax, just ignore whatever is there in `<>` tag; you should be all set.